# Parsing Excel sheet based on date, number of visitors, and printing email

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to parse through an Excel sheet that has columns for the website name (column A), the number of visitors (F), a contact at that website's first name (B), one for last name (C), for email (E), and date it was last modified (L).

I want to write a python script that goes through the sheet and looks at sites that have been modified in the last 3 months and prints out the name of the website and an email.

Comment: You can export excel file into `CSV` file (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) and then it is very easy to parse it into some `list` or other `object` in Python

Comment: `pandas` can read excel sheets for you.

Comment: There are serveral third-party modules that can read (and often write) native Excel files (i.e. in they're native format). What you want to do would probably be fairly simple to do using one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty straightforward to do this. I think a little bit of googling can help you a lot. But in short, you need to use a library called **Pandas** which is a really powerful tool for handling spreadsheets, datasets, and table-based files.
Pandas documentation is very well written. You can use the tutorials provided within the documentation to work your way through the problem easily. However, I'll give you a brief overview of what you should do.

**First** open the spreadsheet (excel file) inside python using Pandas and load it into a data frame (read the docs and you'll understand).
**Second** Using one of the methods provided by pandas called `where` (actually there are a couple of methods) you can easily set a condition (like *if date is older than some data*) and get the masked data frame (which represents your spreadsheet) back from the method.